# SQOOP import from MYSQL to HBASE

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I am trying to import data from mysql to hbase with the below code:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleOne \
--username root \
--password root \
--table SAMPLEDATA \
--columns "ID,NAME,DESIGNATION" \
--hbase-table customers \
--column-family ‘ID’ \   
--hbase-row-key ‘ID,NAME’ \
-m 1
```

But the above code fails saying that `--hbase-row-key command not found` but if I execute `without --hbase-row-key` command then it works like a charm. So what must be the issue ??

Comment: Are you sure it says `command not found` because that's a bash error, not from Sqoop

Comment: yes. I am getting that error

Comment: Try fixing the quotes... `‘ID’` should be `'ID'`and the Hbase row key should be `'ID,NAME'` (if you don't see the difference, actually type the apostrophe)

Comment: yeah i even tried that but same error. Even i tried changing sequence of lines still of no use

Comment: probably an extra space after the \

Comment: not still the same issue